# iptables-restore fails in GKE with error: iptables-restore v1.6.0: Bad IP address ""

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

GKE Cluster:
Get into a pod (kubectl exec -ti ha-77lgb  bash).

```
root@gke-ha-pool-1-10438716-b5wj:/home# iptables-save > /tmp/iptables-save.txt
root@gke-ha-pool-1-10438716-b5wj:/home# iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables-save.txt
iptables-restore v1.6.0: Bad IP address ""

Error occurred at line: 49
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

Why the above error is coming ?? I am not doing anything from my end, just saving and restore back.

Please see line number 49 below:

```
 47 -A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -j MASQUERADE
 48 -A KUBE-SEP-3XFQPLLWSOLEEI2B -s 172.30.192.5/32 -m comment --comment "default/my-nginx2" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
 49 -A KUBE-SEP-3XFQPLLWSOLEEI2B -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/my-nginx2" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination  --random     --persistent --to-destination  --random --persistent --to-destination
 50 -A KUBE-SEP-42YCR4PCVHTERQ6H -s 172.30.192.2/32 -m comment --comment "default/my-nginx2" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
 51 -A KUBE-SEP-42YCR4PCVHTERQ6H -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.30.0.16:80
```

Other information below:

- Installed the iptables in the pod using:

  ```
  RUN apt install -y iptables
  ```
- Included the following in the docker file:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:16.04
  ```
- Build docker image on host machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and pushed the image to GKE cluster.

  Host Machine details:

  ```
  cat  /etc/issue
  Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS \n \l

  root@gke-ha-pool-1-10438716-b5wj:/home# iptables --version
  iptables v1.6.0
  root@gke-ha-pool-1-10438716-b5wj:/home# cat /etc/issue
  Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS \n \l

  root@gke-ha-pool-1-10438716-b5wj:/home# uname -a
  Linux gke-ha-pool-1-10438716-b5wj 5.4.89+ #1 SMP Sat Feb 13 19:45:14 PST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

Sometimes, we also got the following error:

```
iptables-restore v1.6.0: Port `0' not valid
Error occurred at line: 106
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks
-Nagendra

Comment: Indeed the line 49's DNAT rule is missing an IP address as the error tells. That's of course not expected from an `iptables-save` dump, nor the repetition of options: `--to-destination  --random     --persistent --to-destination  --random --persistent --to-destination` . It looks to me there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: As this might also involve the host's kernel, what version is it? Maybe you might try and see if the problem persists or not with a newer kernel on the host and a newer iptables command on the container?

Comment: --to-destination after that you have to specify the  destination IP address which was missing in your 49 line no and also I think you used the same line 2 times: -to-destination  --random     --persistent --to-destination  --random --persistent --to-destination

Comment: @asmath the line is a dump from iptables-save which shouldn't output a faulty line in the first place, that's why it's weird.